# Custom Column Filter on Pivot Table in Excel

Tags: excel-2007, pivot-table

I have an Pivot table in an Excel Sheet where i want to put an custom filter on the label Worktype.
The Worktype can have only 5 values i.e. 
Non Production, REX, QA, RES, BP.
The filter should be like this that:
IF(WorkType Contain only "Non Production) then Show "Non Production" in WorkType, 
else Hide "Non Production" in WorkType and show remaining WorkType (REX,QA,RES,BP)  .

Answer (score 0):

In essence this answer is "you do not need a 'custom' filter, standard features do exactly what you would like done" (if I am understanding your question).

With dummy data as shown and two pivot tables (to show different selections via filter):

[image: SO9390851]

In the smaller pivot table only Non Production is ticked in the filter selection and in the lower pivot table that selection is inverted.

I appreciate this may well not be what you wanted, but if so further clarification may be appropriate.